# using Web Api GET method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

My WEB API has a single GET method as mentioned below which will return a resource based on the id.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
   ....      
}
```

I also have a requirement wherein I need to check 
whether a resource exists or not(no need to return resource).

I would like to know , whether as per the true RESTful service
do I need to write a separate GET for second requirement or use the
existing one.

Comment: You could always return a `NotFound()`.

Comment: I would always expect a GET for a single resource (with an id) to return a 404 if it does not exist.

Comment: @ Mike Eason , so are you suggesting for a new method

Comment: @CleanCrispCode I don't believe he is suggesting that. Simply do your query as normal in the above `Get` if you can't find what they want, return `NotFound()` (so 404) or if you do, return it as normal (200). The user of the API will know if it exists or not from a single call.

Comment: When I only want to check whether resource exists or not , why need to return the resource , thats my only concern.

Comment: It's not mandatory to return resource. Usually if resource exists, developers think of returning resource. Your free to use it the way want, just return Ok().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in your comment, you wish to be able to check if the resource exists without returning it.

For this, you can use `HEAD` as defined [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

> **9.4 HEAD**
>
> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be cacheable in the sense that the information contained in the response MAY be used to update a previously cached entity from that resource. If the new field values indicate that the cached entity differs from the current entity (as would be indicated by a change in Content-Length, Content-MD5, ETag or Last-Modified), then the cache MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

I don't have code to provide you with as an answer on how to implement `HEAD` requests however a quick search yielded [this result](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/03/adding-http-head-support-to-asp-net-web-api/) also [google cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.strathweb.com/2013/03/adding-http-head-support-to-asp-net-web-api/) if direct is down.

Hope that points you in the correct direction!

Answer (score 1):

We can use **IHttpActionResult** of Web API 2 for these kinds of requirements. Here is code snippet. Using **IHttpActionResult** will give proper response to clients with HTTP status codes and response object.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
        {
            //IsResourceExists is method taking  id and return response
            var response = IsResourceExists(id);

            //Assuming 'response' is TRUE
            if (response)
            {
                return Ok(response);
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
```